# python - get next value in list sequence, recursive call

Tags: python, recursion, nextval

What would be the simplest way to get the next value based on a **sorted** list?

Sorted list with unique numbers:

If the number *n* is not found in the list, return **n+1**,
if is found, find in the last number that does not breaks an incremental sequence, return num+1.

- *num=1*,   for the list *[1,2,3,6]* would return ***4***.
- *num=10*,  for the list *[1,2,3,6]* would return ***11***.
- *num=5*,  for the list *[1,2,3,6]* would return ***7***.

I tough about a recursive call, something like:

```
def nextn(num,listnums):
    if(num not in listnums): return num+1
    return nextn(num+1,listnums)

listnums=[1,2,3,6]
n=1
nn = nextn(n,listnums)
print("n=%d nn=%d" %(n,nn))
```

Comment: What's the logic behind your expected outputs?

Comment: If the number n is not found in the list, return n+1, if it is, return the next n+1 in case it is also NOT in the list.

Comment: So just add this explanation to your question.

Comment: I added it, tought my example was enough. thanks

Comment: your if-statement checks for the wrong condition, see below. Actually, your text also states this wrong condition, not what you mean in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Your if-statement is wrong, it is according to your text but not according to your examples.

I found, reversing the if is easier to understand:

```
def nextn(num,listnums):
    if (num+1 in listnums): 
        return nextn(num+1,listnums)
    else:
        return num+1

listnums=[1,2,4]
for n in range(10):
    print("n=%d nn=%d" %(n, nextn(n, listnums)))
```

Comment: you think this is not a solution either? :) but it is, just try

Comment: I think you could improve the answer, adding some explanations.

Comment: thank you, you are right (I commented to the question, but here it's better of course)

Comment: sorry, poke, I see that you edited this, but I saw only after I have overridden it... it's the same, but I don't know how to get the version 3 back...

Comment: No, it’s fine, I didn’t know you were still working on the answer, so I wanted to add the final code, but now that you did it yourself, it’s totally fine :)